# Where lies the mistake in the next proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

We prove the following claim:

> "If $1$ student from a group of n students has graduated, than all students of that group have passed."

For the $n=1$ the claim is trivial. Suppose that we know the claim for $n$ students. So we look at a random group of $n+1$ students from which we know one has graduated. From that group we eliminate one student (not that one from which we know he/she has graduated), so we remain with a group of $n$ students from which one has graduated. The induction hypothesis states that we know that all students have graduated. After which we eliminate another student and we place the student back. The group again contains n students from which certainly 1 student has graduated (there are already $n-1$ graduated students) and again the induction hypothesis states that this last student has also graduated. So we have completed the proof..... still the "reality" learns us that the claim isn't always true.

$\text{Where lies the mistake?}$

I first thought that the mistake lay in the fact that you also need to take out the student who already graduated which will automaticaly falsify the proof. But then I'm not sure about this because you need to have that one graduated student to prove the claim.

Can somebody please explain me what the mistake is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color

Comment: Play the $n\to n+1$ step through for $n=1$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHSeOizSvjc  may show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Oh , ok I see. It is false when you consider n = 2 students because of the missing link which is the middle group.

Comment: or the set intersection in set theory group technically is a bad word to use as it has other math meanings.